# Can anyone help me to launch front camera by default in android 7+ devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I have a requirement to capture selfie for my android app. but enable to launch front camera by default on button click. Can anyone help me to open it by default.
i tried with these code snippet but not succeed for front camera. back is working fine.

```
private fun launchCamera() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
}

and

private fun launchCamera() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
            cameraIntent.putExtra(
                "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
                CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            ) 
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
            cameraIntent.putExtra(
                "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
                CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            ) 
            cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
        }
        else -> cameraIntent.putExtra(
            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
            1
        )
    }
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
}
```